# Javascript - detect when image loaded

Tags: javascript, while-loop, undefined

I have a function that, among other things, grabs a `data` attribute from an element and uses it for some calculations. The problem is that the attribute is assigned only once the element's background image has loaded.

Since the function is firing before the background image has loaded, the variable I'm looking for is undefined (and therefore causing other issues). I thought I would fix that by having a `while` loop for when the variable is undefined. If that variable *is* undefined, keep checking for it until it's not:

```
while ($(".element").data("ui-color") == "undefined"){
    var color = "" // keep it blank until the attribute exists
}
```

Then once after the loop is no longer true, assign the variable:

```
var color = $(".element").data("ui-color");
```

The problem is that it seems to be disregarding the while loop and still  resulting in an undefined variable.

Is there some other condition I should be using for the while loop (or some other method completely)?

Comment: If the `ui-color` is set from an asynchronous task, such as an image's `load` event, then a loop like this will actually prevent it from finishing. JavaScript is (mainly) single-threaded and that thread will be too busy with the loop to handle the event. You'll need to bind the code you want to execute to the same event or have the code that sets `ui-color` [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a new event so that it just sits idle in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use JavaScript's `Image.onload` event, and execute the loop once the image has loaded.

Example:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  // your calculations here
}
img.src = 'path/to/file';
```

The `onload` event will fire once the image is fully downloaded and displayed by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see in a different way, use on load event on the background image. like

```
$("#background").on("load",function() { console.log("blah") }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this doesn't actually solve the problem, but instead identifies an error in the code

Make this change for your code to work

```
typeof $(".element").data("ui-color") == "undefined"
```

The `typeof` operator will evaluate the left-hand side to the string literal 'undefined' which is what looks like you intended to do.

Comment: I tried that before, but it then seems to be stuck in an infinite loop and locks up the browser :/

Comment: The other answers and comments explain a solution to your problem. Try those. My answer fixes an error in your code but it won't solve your problem.